# Images not showing in div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add an image on my website, but it's not working my code is below

```css
div#planet {
  z-index: -10;
  width: 450px;
  height: 549px;
  position: absolute;
  background: url("http://heroic.cosmicpvp.com/images/planet.jpg") no-repeat top center;
  top: -75px;
  right: -450px;
}
```

```html
<div id="planet"></div>
```

Comment: Hi James. Could you please add a bit more context to the question (a valid html page would be helpful) ?.

Comment: I'm assuming that div style code is enclosed in <style>. Try changing background -> background-image

Comment: Your top and right are off ... remove them or change them and it would show.

Comment: problem is with right:-450px;... if you try it at -75px, its working.....

Answer (score 1):

Try this fiddle. It works fine.

https://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/4qtum631/4/

```css
#planet {
  z-index: 9;
  width: 100%;
  height: 549px;
  background: url("http://heroic.cosmicpvp.com/images/planet.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:top center; 
}
```

```html
<div id="planet"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/4qtum631/4/

Answer (score 1):

Can't guess why did you use right and top property to minus value. Its relocating the view port on origin of -75 from top and -450 on right. So its actually left the window.

Just remove them. The background image should visible.

```
div#planet {
   z-index: -10;
   width: 450px;
   height: 549px;
   position: absolute;
   background: url("http://heroic.cosmicpvp.com/images/planet.jpg") no-repeat top center;
   margin: 0;
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JaKXOG)

Answer (score 1):

As @Akrion and @Dr M J  mentioned in comments, your positioning of `top` and `right` were pushing the `<div>` off the page.

Removing those two lines of code will resolve the issue:

```
    div#planet {
        width: 450px;
        height: 549px;
        z-index: -10;
        background: url("http://heroic.cosmicpvp.com/images/planet.jpg") no-repeat top center; */
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 div#planet {
    width: 450px;
    height: 549px;
    z-index: -10;
    background: url("http://heroic.cosmicpvp.com/images/planet.jpg") no-repeat top center; /* use this this will helpfull */
}
```